# Is it legit to compare strings of times like this?

Tags: python, string, datetime, time, compare

```
print("00:00:00"<"24:00:00")
```

this give true. But is it legitimate, to compare the intraday time like this?
I mean does python understand that i mean times? (or at least that these strings are "like" numbers in terms of size)

Comment: Python doesn't need to understand that they're times, as long as the string comparison produces the same result as a time comparison.  For a string in the format `hh:mm:ss` this will be true, except that the hour starting at midnight might be `00:00:00` or `24:00:00`.

Comment: Python will _not_ understand that you mean time, since what you had supplied was a `str` value (computers will never do what you mean, it will do exactly what it was instructed); if you really want to deal with a time, convert the value to a datetime type; do note that `24:00:00` is not considered a valid time - not to mention that it may be considered equivalent to `00:00:00`.

Comment: That work fine, but not because Python knows you're comparing times. The only thing it knows is that you're comparing _strings_. So long as you have leading zeroes, though, string comparison works the same in this context as if you were comparing times. But, .e.g., "09:00:00" < "5:00:00" is also true. As _strings_ "0" < "5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're technically comparing two str objects (string/text). This could be valid if you use 24-hour format:

```
type("00:00:00") # str i.e. string, not time

"09:00:00"<"21:00:00" # True

"12:00:00 pm" < "11:00:00 pm" # False
```

EDIT: Removed the initial am/pm suggestion due to 12pm exception.

Answer (score 1):

First

24 is not a legit hour, it should be "0-23"

Second

In your formate it is legit. I mean your time formate is "hh:mm:ss". It could be compare by string like what you did.

Third

I have a common method to compare time. It requires `python-dateutil` package.

Install package by pip install python-dateutil

Then

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
print(parse("00:00:00")<parse("23:00:00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does NOT understand that these strings represent time. It only understands that they are strings. Python does not do any sort of string parsing to try to interpret what you mean when you create strings - this would be incredibly inefficient and unnecessary for 99.9% of use cases.

That being said, there are built-in conversions that you can call to convert strings to other types. A simple example is the conversion from string to float. In this case, you are explicitly telling Python to interpret the string a particular way, which is why it works:

```py
float("5.3")  # Returns 5.3 as a floating point number
```

The reason that your time comparison works is that Python will compare strings by looking at each character, starting from the beginning of the string, and comparing the ASCII values of those characters. Essentially, Python will compare the strings with respect to alphabetical order (more accurately, based on ASCII value). In your example, the first characters that will be compared are `'0'` and `'2'`. Character `'2'` has an ASCII value of 50, which is larger than `'0'`'s ASCII value of 48. At this point, Python can already conclude that the 2nd string is larger than the 1st string, so it returns `True`. If the two characters were identical, it would have continued reading from left-to-right until it could make a decision as to which string is "less".

See the [ASCII Table](http://cs.smu.ca/%7Eporter/csc/ref/ascii.html) for more information on ASCII codes.